# matrix multiplication, change in order

Tags: matrices

I need to change the order of the matrix multiplication in the form $A \cdot B C$ where $A$ is $2 \times 2$, $B$ is $2 \times 3$ and $C$ is $3 \times 3$ matrix. Is it true $A \cdot B C=C^T A \cdot B$ where $C^T$ is the first 2 row transpose of matrix $C$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $C^T$? (Bad notation as $C^T$ means something else.)

Comment: What's the meaning of the dot $\cdot$ as opposed to not dot ?

Answer (score 0):

No, since $ABC$ is a $2\times3$ matrix, whereas $C^TAB$ is a $3\times3$ matrix.

Comment: I don't think he means the real transpose $C^T$.

Comment: Actually, $C^T$ is the transpose of $C$ matrix with $3 \times 2$ dimension. Sorry for the notation, i.e

Comment: @zhivago   This makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here $A$ is $2 \times 2$, $B$ is $2 \times 3$ and $C$ is $3 \times 3$ matrix i.e., Let $$A=(a_{ij})_{2 \times 2}\quad B=(b_{ij})_{2 \times 3},  \quad C=(c_{ij})_{3 \times 3}\quad \text{and}\quad C^T=(c_{ji})_{3 \times 3}$$

**Case I:**

Now if $A \cdot B C=C^T A \cdot B \implies A(BC)=(C^TA)B$, then I must tell you that it is not possible because of their order.

**Explanation:**

Here $BC=(p_{ij})_{2 \times 3}\quad \text{but}\quad C^TA\quad$is not defined (by matrix multiplication rule).

And therefore $A \cdot B C=C^T A \cdot B$ is not possible.

**Case II:**

Now if $A \cdot B C=C^T A \cdot B \implies (AB)C=C^T(AB)$, then I must tell you that it is not possible because of their order.

**Explanation:**

Here $AB=(k_{ij})_{2 \times 3},\quad (AB)C=(g_{ij})_{2 \times 3}\quad \text{and}\quad C^T(AB)\quad$ is again not defined due to the same reason.

${}$

> If $A$ is an $n × m$ matrix and $B$ is an $m × p$ matrix, their matrix product $AB$ is an $n × p$ matrix, in which the $m$ entries across a row of $A$ are multiplied with the $m$ entries down a column of $B$ and summed to produce an entry of $AB$.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication